# Does mmu_notifier_invalidate_*() work on ARM in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kvm

In the Linux kernel, does mmu_notifier_invalidate_*() work on ARM?

I know it works on X86(Intel) for invalidating mappings in EPT.
However, on ARM, I doubt it works.

I'm looking for a similar function on ARM.

Comment: Does your ARM have an MMU?

Comment: Hi Stark, I think so. Would this affect mmu_notifier_invalidate_page()? And how? --Thanks,

Comment: There are many 'mm/proc-xxx.S' that have function pointers for cache and MMU features on ARM.  Maybe you want to 'override' one of these?  I am not sure what your use case is.  The interface is [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/proc-fns.h?h=v5.18-rc1) and other headers for [cache](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/cacheflush.h?h=v5.18-rc1), etc.